# How to read application/pdf content type from HttpResponseMessage and convert it into stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I have a Web API which  connects to another end point. A GET method from the second Web API returns an application/pdf content-type.   here I am successfully getting the data. How I can convert the response.Content to file/memory stream and return the value?

```
 public async Task<T> functionname<T>(ApplicationApiRoutes.APIRoutes route, string token = "", int TimeoutMinutes = 5, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default, params string[] routeparams)
    {
        T Response = default;
        try
        {
            ApplicationApiRoutes._RouteHashTable.TryGetValue(route, out string FormattedRoute);

            FormattedRoute = String.Format(FormattedRoute, routeparams);

            using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{FormattedRoute}"))
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
                {
                    request.Headers.Add("Cookie", $"access_token="+ token);
                }
                
               

                using (var response = await _httpclient
                    .SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, cancellationToken))
                {

                    
                   
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

                    Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(result, _jsonsettings);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
           
        }

        return Response;
    }
```

Comment: Ah, so you have a generic function that converts json to some type T. You can't treat a pdf as json. IMHO write a new method that just returns the body stream and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to download the file after retrieving it, try the following in your controller action method:

```
var fileStream = new MemoryStream();

using (var file = await _httpClient.GetStreamAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
{
      await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
}

fileStream.Position = 0;  
return File(fileStream , "application/pdf", "filename.pdf");
```

Comment: Before this I need to convert it some how and pass the converted value to the controller from manager

Comment: You can use the same code, just return Stream in your method in your manager with the memory stream object and then run the rest of the code in the Action... public Stream GetFile() { etc...

Comment: For GetStreamAsync(request) parameter will be uri string. And in my endponits i need to pass auth tocken in cookies. So is there any alternative we can use?

Comment: You can (and should) put that in the default headers of your httpClient instance ;) If you post the complete code the manager I can try to change it.

Comment: Now I have added the complete function above

Comment: Why do you have a list of routes? Do they always return a pdf? Wouldnt it be better to add a method for each API call, especific to what it does?

Comment: Actually my application contain lot of end point calls. All others are returning jason data.So each end points different function is not possible. Only this one is returning pdf. For the pdf one i can create a new one but how we can pass the cookies and get data using getstreamasync.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, $"{url}")
{
   Content = new StringContent("")
};
request.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/pdf");
HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        if (response.Content.Headers.ContentType.MediaType == "application/pdf")
        {
          byte[] pdfBytes = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
          File.WriteAllBytes("file.pdf", pdfBytes);
        }
        else
        {
        throw new Exception("is not PDF content");
        }
    }
    else
    {
      throw new Exception(response.RequestMessage.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).